# Using jsonencode with length 1 array

Tags: arrays, json, matlab

When using the MATLAB `jsonencode` function it seems very difficult to convert size 1 arrays into the correct JSON format i.e. [value]. For example if I do:

```
jsonencode(struct('words', [string('hello'), string('bye')]))
```

Then this produces:

```
{"words":["hello","bye"]}
```

which is correct. If however I do:

```
jsonencode(struct('words', [string('hello')]))
```

Then it produces:

```
{"words":"hello"}
```

losing the square brackets, which it needs because it is in general an array. The same happens when using a cell rather than an array, although using a cell does work if it's not inside a struct.

Any idea how I can work around this issue?

Comment: The problem is related to the fact that matlab makes no difference between a single value and a 1x1 matrix.

Comment: I guess the easiest way to do this would be to always add a garbage/temporary word at the end of your string, to make sure it has more than a single word, forcing MATLAB to use the square brackets. Then in JSON remove the garbage word in post-processing. The more difficult way would be to read the cell-output and rewrite that with square brackets at the appropriate positions; probably requiring a regex.

Comment: The structure is automatically converted to JSON as part of an http request, so I would have to change the code to do the JSON conversion on the client side and pass through the data as a string rather than as a structure. So I guess it would be possible but messy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems this can be solved by using a cell rather than an array and then not creating the struct inline. Like

```
s.words = {'hello'};
jsonencode(s)
```

Output:

```
{"words":["hello"]}
```

I presume when created inline the cell functionality of matlab is actually trying to make multiple structs rather than multiple strings. Note that this still won't work with arrays as matlab treats a size one array as a scalar.